# How do I make the same alteration to individual files in a directory?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, glob, listdir

I have a directory that the full set of csv files I would like to make alterations to.  Each csv has a row that has date, and I would like to add a column that counts down from the length of the file down to 1 (so the last, most recent date in the file would have a value of 1 in that column.

I have tried the following:

```
>import os
>import pandas as pd

>for f in os.listdir(path):

>    df = pd.read_csv(f)

>    df['Countdown'] = range(len(df), 1, -1)
```

This gives me an error of

> FileNotFoundError: File b'Data.csv' does not exist

Which is odd as it gives the specific name of the Data file that is in the directory, so it can clearly see the file as it is using it's name in the error message.

I have tried using glob as well.

```
>import glob

>data_set = glob.glob(path)

>for f in data_set:

>    df = pd.read_csv(f)

>    df['Countdown'] = range(len(df), 1, -1)
```

This does not work as it says:

> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

This error makes sense to me, as the length of the dataframe is constantly increasing as I add more files to it, so the 'len(df)' argument is changing and doesn't match the indexes.

I'm confident that what I'm trying to do isn't too unique, I'm just having trouble finding the best way to perform this task.  Again, the outcome I'm looking for it to have individual files that each have a column that counts down from the earliest date to be the length of the dataframe, and the most recent date having a value of 1.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: `df['new'] = np.arange(len(df), 0, -1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for f in glob.glob(r'/path/to/dir/*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    df['Countdown'] = np.arange(len(df), 0, -1)
    # process df...
```

Comment: This correctly does the countdown, but because it globs everything together, it does not do this on each file individually. It combines all the files into one dataframe, then counts down once.  I am looking to have it countdown for EACH file.  If I have 20 files, it should countdown 20 times.